# Go/C++ gRPC client channel and stub lifecycle

Tags: c++, go, grpc

I have several Go and C++ services, that act as servers and clients, i.e. those are long-living services, that from time-to-time talk to other services.

I cannot find anywhere in gRPC docs whether the client channels and stubs should be long-lasting reusable objects or they should be created on every call. Or, maybe, I should create some kind of a channel/stub pool, where a pair of a channel and a stub exists, for example, for each thread and gets updated, refreshed on some interval or condition.

Comment: They are supposed to be long living. Reconnecting themselves if the connection drops in the meantime.

Comment: One channel is generally exactly one HTTP/2 connection (and each call is one stream in that connection). With a loadbalancer it may be several connections. In any case, you're supposed to reuse that channel as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

According to official docs, you are encouraged to reuse **stubs** and **channels** when possible.

https://grpc.io/docs/guides/performance/